# Как склонять фамилию Грелек

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Надо ли склонять фамилию Игор Грелек (Igor Hrelek)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно предположить, что фамилия в м.р. склоняется: Игоря Грелека

В случае склонения мужских фамилий, оканчивающихся на - ок, - ек, - ец, возникает вопрос: сохранять ли беглый гласный?
Воронец – Воронеца или Воронца?
Гришковец – Гришковеца или Гришковца?
Волчек – Волчека или Волчка?
Мазурок – Мазурока или Мазурка?

Общее правило: При склонении фамилий, оканчивающихся на - ок, - ек, гласный о/е сохраняется.
При склонении фамилий, оканчивающихся на - ец, гласный е «убегает»:
напр., в род.п. - Гришковца, но! Волчека, Мазурока.

Для сравнения:При склонении чешских фамилий типа Горачек, Филипец, “е” остается: Горачека, Филипеца
http://www.yourtalk.eu/uptodate/2010/01/склонение-имен-и-фамилий/

Answer (score 1):

Склонять (вариант, что это женское имя, считаю фантастическим).

И. кто? Игор Грелек
Р. кого? Игора Грелека
Д. кому? Игору Грелеку
В. кого? Игора Грелека
Т. кем? Игорем Грелеком
П. о ком? (об) Игоре Грелеке

Обратите внимание, что перед е согласная смягчается, но в остальных случаях остается твердой. 
Чешский вариант склонения (с выпадением е в суффиксе) в русском совершенно невозможен по грамматике. А в Вашем случае он еще бы и приводил бы к нежелательному комическому эффекту.

Comment: Решите, у нас имя Игорь или Игор. Если Игор, то Т.п. (кем?) Игором.